# How to set selected value for multiple Pickers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen with a button upon pressing which, a new view with a picker will be rendered. How do I set selectedValue for these pickers, if they all should be independent from each other?

I tried using an array and passing indices as an argument to the view generating function, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Picker, Button } from "react-native";

export default class SessionScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    externalData: ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3", "Player4"],
    view: [],
    selectedPlayers: []
  };

  async view(index) {
    let players = this.state.externalData.map((s, i) => {
      return <Picker.Item key={i} value={s} label={s} />;
    });
    let newVal = (
      <View
        key={this.state.selectedPlayers[index] + "view" + index}
        style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", paddingTop: 60 }}
      >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <Picker
            key={this.state.selectedPlayers[index] + "picker" + index}
            selectedValue={this.state.selectedPlayers[index - 1]}
            style={{ height: 50, width: 200 }}
            onValueChange={itemValue =>
              this.setState(prevState => ({
                selectedPlayers: [...prevState.selectedPlayers, itemValue]
              }))
            }
          >
            {players}
          </Picker>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
    await this.setState(prevState => ({
      view: [...prevState.view, newVal]
    }));
  }

  async addPlayer() {
    await this.view(this.state.selectedPlayers.length);
  }

  render() {
    var returnValue = [];
    if (this.state.view.length > 0) returnValue = [...this.state.view];
    returnValue.push(
      <View
        key={returnValue.length + 1}
        style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", paddingTop: 100 }}
      >
        <Button
          title="Add a player"
          onPress={this.addPlayer.bind(this)}
          accessibilityLabel="Add a new player to the table"
        >
          Add a player
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
    return returnValue;
  }
}
```

When Add A Player button is pressed, a new Picker appears on the screen. When I pick a different value from the given items, it is still displaying 'Player1'. But when I press 'Add a Player' again, the value I had chosen in the first picker appears in the second one.

I am sure it's not the best approach to solving this problem and I am open to suggestions. 
P.S. It's my third day trying to do something in react-native, or react at all.